# Результат с function_score/

Tags: elasticsearch

Здравствуйте. Мне нужно в результат поиска рассматривать приоритет фирмы. В документации есть похожая опция "Boosting Filtered Subsetsedit". В рузультате я получаю вот такой json запроса и получаю ошибку. Возможно я не в такой последовательности вкладываю запрос на фильтрацию. Подскажите в какой последовательности нужно написать вопрос учитывая фильтрацию.

```
{
"index":"base",
"type":"info",
"from":0,
"size":10,
"fields":["cID","firm_html"],
"body":
       {
        "query":
                {
                "bool":
                      {
                       "must_not":[
                                  {
                                  "match":
                                         {
                                        "info.published":"no"
                                         }
                                  }
                                  ],
                       "should":[
                                {
                                "query_string":
                                               {
                                                "default_field":
                                                    "info.shortname",
                                                    "query":"value"
                                                }
                                },
                                {
                                "match":
                                        {
                                        "_all":"value"
                                        }
                                },
                                ]
                       },
                "function_score":
                                {
                                "functions":[
                                            {
                                            "filter":
                                                     {
                                                 "term":
                                                        {
                                                         "razm_prio":"0.4"
                                                        }
                                                 },
                                            "weight":"0.4"
                                            },
                                            ],
                                "score_mode":"sum"
                                }
                }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Действительно у вас нарушена последовательность, query с фильтрацией должен быть внутри function_score.

```js
{
"index":"base",
"type":"info",
"from":0,
"size":10,
"fields": ["cID","firm_html"],
"query": {
    "function_score": {
        "score_mode":"sum",
        "functions": [
            {
                "filter": {
                    "term": {
                        "razm_prio": 0.4
                    }
                },
                "weight": 0.4
            }
        ],
        "query": {
            "bool": {
               "must_not": [
                    {
                        "match": {"info.published":"no"}
                    }
                ],
               "should": [
                    {
                        "query_string": {
                            "default_field": "info.shortname",
                            "query":"value"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "match": {"_all":"value"}
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```